# Unit testing ag-grid in Angular 2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ag-grid

Has someone worked on unit testing ag-grid components in Angular 2?

For me, this.gridOptions.api remains undefined when the test cases run.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to be a little late to the party but I was looking for an answer to this just a couple of days ago so wanted to leave an answer for anyone else that ends up here. As mentioned by Minh above, the modern equivalent of `$digest` does need to be run in order for ag-grid api's to be available.

This is because after the `onGridReady()` has run you have access to the api's via the parameter, looking like so. This is run automatically when a component with a grid is initialising. Providing it is defined in the grid `(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"`

```
public onGridReady(params)
{
   this.gridOptions = params;
}
```

This now means you could access `this.gridOptions.api` and it would be defined, you need to re-create this in your test by running `detectChanges()`. Here is how I got it working for my project.

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

fixture.detectChanges(); // This will ensure the onGridReady(); is called
```

This should inturn result in `.api` being defined when running tests. This was Angular 6.

Occasionally the test may have to perform an await or a tick:

```
  it('should test the grid', fakeAsync( async () => {
    // also try tick(ms) if a lot of data is being tested
    // try to keep test rows as short as possible
    // this line seems essential at times for onGridReady to be processed.
    await fixture.whenStable();
    // perform your expects...after the await
  }));
```

Comment: At times you will need to also use a fakeAsync call with maybe a tick(10) for instance, and even an await fixture.whenStable() clause to ensure the grid is fully initialised. For some reason the grid takes a few ms to settle in size, it will then call onGridReady.

Comment: I hadn't tried that, feel free to edit it into the answer if you think its useful :-)

Comment: I've now provided an update. Please re-edit if you have further comments.

Comment: lovely stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ag-grid enterprise make sure to include in your test file `import 'ag-grid-enterprise';` otherwise you will see console errors and gridReady will never be called:

```
Row Model "Server Side" not found. Please ensure the ag-Grid Enterprise Module @ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model is registered.';
```

Comment: I had this exact same issue while testing ag-grid in angular. The grid use to work perfectly fine however during UT it use to throw this error. Adding importing ag-grid-enterprise in spec file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It remains undefined because the event onGridReady is not invoked yet. Im not sure about Angular 2 because im using angularjs and have to do $digest in order to invoke onGridReady.