# gridOptions.api is null when onGridReady event fires after checking gridOptions.api to be defined in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In my `onGridReady` event, I'm assigning `api` to `this.gridApi`.

```
private onGridReady(gridReadyEvent: GridReadyEvent): void {
  this.gridApi = gridReadyEvent.api;
}
```

I have a method in which I'm using `this.gridApi`.

```
public getGridState(): GridState {
    if (this.gridApi) { 
      // code to get state
    }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test for `getGridState`.

**Unit test**:

```
it('should be able to get state of grid', async () => {
  waitForGridApiToBeAvailable(component.gridOptions, () => {
    component.getGridState();
  });
});
```

So, in order to make sure `this.gridApi` is defined, I'm using `waitForGridApiToBeAvailable` mentioned in [ag-Grid unit testing doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-e2e-test-with-jasmine/#unit-testing). So, this would mean when `gridOptions.api` is defined, `this.gridApi` would be too, right?

**The issue**:

When I run my unit test, it does call `component.getGridState()` only after `component.gridOptions.api` is defined but `this.gridApi` is `undefined` in `getGridState()`.

Apart from this, the thing that baffle me more is that `onGridReady()` is getting called after `getGridState()` is called and when I consoled `this.gridOptions.api`, it turned out to be `null`. How can `this.gridOptions.api` be `null` when `getGridState()` was called from the unit test after it checked `component.gridOptions.api` to be defined and `onGridReady()` was called after `getGridState()`?

**Note**: I've tried to explain as much as clearly I could. Let me know if something needs more explanation.

Comment: I think I answered something very similar a while back, see if it helps :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299256/unit-testing-ag-grid-in-angular-2/55483100#55483100

Comment: @Dince12 I'm already using `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Comment: Probably, you need to bind onGridReady to your unit test module. Try console(this) inside onGridReady to make sure that 'this' is what you think it is.